# PHP mailer with WordPress - how to pull admin email?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, phpmailer

I'm trying to use a mailer in my WordPress theme, but I don't seem to be able to pull admin email from WordPress.

I have a mailer.php file in my theme folder and tried using `get_bloginfo('admin_email')` function but it doesn't work. I'm a PHP newbie, but I'm guessing the mailer.php file isn't "connected" to WordPress installation. I tried including it in the functions.php file, but it only caused my theme to go blank.

So my question is, how do I pull WordPress functions in files, that aren't theme files?

To answer Pekka's comment - I get an error:
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  get_bloginfo() in mailer.php on line 4

Comment: First off, activate error reporting to get definite information on what goes wrong. If you use `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, the script will tell you exactly what doesn't work out

Comment: Done. That's what I'm getting in mailer.php - it doesn't know WordPress functions, why I'm guessing it's "not connected" to WP, despite being in the theme folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import WordPress's functions using

```
include "/path/to/your/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php";
```

After that, you will be able to call `get_bloginfo()`.